# Using Selenium with Python to select a check box in Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've read multiple threads where a similar question has been asked, but unfortunately none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I am trying to select/click a checkbox through Chrome. The Html is:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" width="100%" bgcolor="white" border="0">
    <tr align="center">
        <td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" align="left"><b></b></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap"><b><font color="#E46C0A"></font></b></td>       <td style="cursor: help;" bgcolor="#BBBBBB">
            <b>Last Published</b>
        </td>       <td style="cursor: help;" bgcolor="#BBBBBB">
            <b></b>
        </td>       <td style="cursor: help;" bgcolor="#BBBBBB">
            <b>+/-</b>
        </td>       <td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#BBBBBB">
            <b>%</b>
        </td><td bgcolor="#BBBBBB"><b>&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</b></td>       </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="7">&nbsp;<b>India domestic</b></td>
</tr><tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="left"><a href="http://steelbb.com/?PageID=93&series_id=605" class="brf_series">TS01046 - HRC India Domestic - DDP Mumbai Wkly, INR/t</a></td><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
&nbsp;35250&nbsp;-&nbsp;35250&nbsp;
</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;Dec 04&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" align="center">w</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap"><font color="#1D6A0F" style="nowrap:nowrap">+1000.00</font></td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;<font color="#1D6A0F">+2.3%</font>&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><input type="checkbox" name="FPR_cb[605]" value="1"  /></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="7">&nbsp;<b>N.Europe domestic</b></td>
</tr><tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="left"><a href="http://steelbb.com/?PageID=93&series_id=432" class="brf_series">STHRE00 - Platts TSI North European HRC - EXW Ruhr, &euro;/t</a></td><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
&nbsp;427.5000&nbsp;
</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;Dec 04&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" align="center">d</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">0.0000</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;0.0%&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><input type="checkbox" name="FPR_cb[432]" value="1"  /></td></tr><tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="left"><a href="http://steelbb.com/?PageID=93&series_id=434" class="brf_series">STRRE00 - Platts TSI North European CRC - EXW Ruhr, &euro;/t</a></td><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
&nbsp;520&nbsp;
</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;Dec 04&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" align="center">d</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">0.0000</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;0.0%&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><input type="checkbox" name="FPR_cb[434]" value="1"  /></td></tr><tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="left"><a href="http://steelbb.com/?PageID=93&series_id=11" class="brf_series">SB01125 - Platts TSI North European HDG Coil - Ex-Works, base price, &euro;/t</a></td><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
&nbsp;532.50&nbsp;
```

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@name='FPR-cb[82]']").click()

driver.find_element_by_name('FPR-cb[82]').send_keys('1')
```

I can't find an id and am a bit lost.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Added:
I've added some additional Html code (it's not pretty, sorry). And i can see that each of the prices that i am required to select have another name such as 'TS01046 - HRC India Domestic - DDP Mumbai Wkly, INR', so could i use this rather than the 'FPR_cb[605]' name i have been trying to use? Note this particular check box is different to my first example, but they are all similar.

Added:
I feel i need to add that rather than open each price (which takes me to a graph), i want to multi select the check-boxes and then download all of them. I i follow the href links it doesn't allow me to then select more prices at the same time. I want to select around 15 prices in total.
Thanks,

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML

Comment: @DebanjanB I have updated the html and added to my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you should not use send_keys but you should use .click() function. But if you cant select the item. Can we have additional HTML tags like above of that tag?

use

```
//input[@name='FPR_cb[432]']
```

although based on your xpath. It looks like the name tag is changing upon refresh or transaction. (not permanent tag value). Would like to know where we can anchor like a label above or table tag